# THREE.js - Render an Object only when in front of another object

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it possible to only Render the Part of Object 2 that obscures Object 1.

Essentially using Object 1 as a mask? Trying to recreate the effect of CanvasRenderingComposite destination-in in 3D using THREEjs

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking to change the [`Material.depthFunc` attribute](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/Material.depthFunc). By default, it's set to `LessEqualDepth`, and according to the documentation:

> `LessEqualDepth` is the default and will return true if the incoming pixel Z-depth is less than or equal to the current buffer Z-depth.

That means that choosing the opposite would give you the result that you want: either with `GreaterEqualDepth` or `GreaterDepth`:

> `GreaterEqualDepth` will return true if the incoming pixel Z-depth is greater than or equal to the current buffer Z-depth.

You should be able to get the desired result with:

`object2.material.depthFunc = THREE.GreaterEqualDepth;`, or assigning it as an option when creating the material.

If you want to look at the other depthFunction possibilities, you can take a look at the [Materials constants page](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/constants/Materials) and scroll down a little to the "Depth Mode" section.